# sudo: java: command not found after exiting from root user

Tags: java, bash, unix, sudo

I have installed jdk but when I tried to use the java command it said "command not found".

So I then set the environment variable for my account in .bashrc and it works okay.

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_03
export CLASSPATH=.:$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/rt.jar:$JAVA_HOME/lib/dt.jar:$JAVA_HOME/l\
ib/tools.jar
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
```

However when I try to use sudo to execute java it says that again. So I used `sudo -s` to switch to root, put those into /etc/profile, and executed `source /etc/profile`

This works if I keep logged in as root but after I return to my own account and use `sudo java` it still says sudo: java: command not found and those environment variables become blank.

What should I do to solve the problem? I guess it should be easy to solve.

Comment: Why are you using `sudo` to run Java under your own account? You don't need it; just run `java` directly.

Comment: @KenWhite Well it's just a test. The crux is that the root account cannot preserve the envs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some distros, by default, reset your environment variables to ensure programs executed under root run as expected.  Any environment variable not specified in a whitelist is not carried into your root session.

The instruction to reset to environment as well as what variables to allow is defined in `/etc/sudoers`.  (You need permissions to view/edit this).

For example, on my Fedora 16 box, I have

```
Defaults    env_reset
Defaults    env_keep =  "COLORS DISPLAY HOSTNAME HISTSIZE INPUTRC KDEDIR LS_COLORS"
Defaults    env_keep += "MAIL PS1 PS2 QTDIR USERNAME LANG LC_ADDRESS LC_CTYPE"
Defaults    env_keep += "LC_COLLATE LC_IDENTIFICATION LC_MEASUREMENT LC_MESSAGES"
Defaults    env_keep += "LC_MONETARY LC_NAME LC_NUMERIC LC_PAPER LC_TELEPHONE"
Defaults    env_keep += "LC_TIME LC_ALL LANGUAGE LINGUAS _XKB_CHARSET XAUTHORITY"
```

Note that `XAUTHORITY` isn't there by default, [I had to add it](http://blog.edwards-research.com/2012/06/x-forwarding-with-sudo/).

If you want your `JAVA_HOME` envvar to carry over, you could add it here.  However, for this to be all you need to do, you'd need to add `PATH` to this list and that is really discouraged.

So also in this file is a line like the following:

```
Defaults    secure_path = /sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
```

This will be your `$PATH` inside your sudo session.  Just ensure that you have a symlink to the java executable you want to use in one of those folders, and you'll be fine.

(Since you are getting the "command not found message", there are no `java` executables on your secure path, but if there were, you'd need to either remove it, or place your new symlink "higher" (earlier) in the path)

**Alternative 1**

Add an alias to `java` (eg `alias java='/usr/java/latest/bin/java'`) inside a file like `/etc/bashrc`

**Alternative 2**

Add an alias to `java` in your local profile or bashrc files and an alias to `sudo` [that will preserve your aliases](http://blog.edwards-research.com/2010/07/keeping-aliases-with-sudo-sort-of/).

Comment: Well I added "JAVA_HOME" to env_keep and it works. Not sure if it's the correct way to solve the problem or just because of luck. Correct me if it harms security.

Comment: The extent to which it affects security is pretty small.  You've opened yourself up to a malicious program/user changing that env. var. on your user account to point to a different malicious java install that, when run via sudo, gives root privileges to the malicious java, not the expected java.  I'd feel comfortable doing what you did without worrying about a huge security vulnerability.  Happy it helped.

Answer (score 2):

man sudo will give you the answer:

```
  -E   The -E (preserve environment) option indicates to the security policy that the user wishes
       to preserve their existing environment variables.  The security policy may return an error 
       if the -E option is specified and the user does not have permission to preserve the environment.
```

Comment: sudo -E java -version still gives sudo: java: command not found. I guess I'm not using it correctly?

Comment: Also switching to root using sudo -s and echo $JAVA_HOME still gives blank

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use something like `update-alternatives` (not sure if this is available on all distros).

It creates and manages symlinks in /usr/bin (ie. executables available to all).

Example usage: `sudo update-alternatives --install java java /path/to/java/home/bin/java`

I think java can then extract the location of `JAVA_HOME` based on it's executable location.

Answer (score 0):

Check the permission on the jdk folder, make sure it's `rwx`.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by

```
vi /etc/sudoers
```

and then put $JAVA_HOME/bin in

```
Defaults        secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin:$JAVA_HOME/bin"
```