# neo4j start causes ERROR: JAVA_HOME is incorrectly defined

Tags: ubuntu, neo4j

I'm trying to run the neo4j server on an Ubuntu machine using this command:

```
sudo neo4j start
```

But it gives me this error:

```
ERROR: JAVA_HOME is incorrectly defined as /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64/bin/ (the executable /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64/bin//bin/java does not exist)
```

Now, I have set `JAVA_HOME` to the correct directory where Java is installed. Here is what I get when I run `echo $JAVA_HOME`:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
```

I don't know where it's getting that value for `JAVA_HOME`. I checked the configuration files but I couldn't find any variables referring to `JAVA_HOME` that I might need to set.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27319495/error-java-home-is-not-defined-correctly-executing-maven. Note the comment about ubuntu under the accepted answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the same problem with 7 and you can fix it like this:

`JAVA_HOME` should be set to the name of the directory that contains the bin directory that contains the Java executables (in particular, java itself).

Assuming you do have a `/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0` directory, it probably contains a `jre` subdirectory that contains the `bin` directory that contains java and related executables.

So you should probably be setting `JAVA_HOME` to `/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0/jre` rather than `/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0`.

See
[JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly](https://askubuntu.com/questions/157229/java-home-is-not-defined-correctly) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

Some distros, by default, reset your environment variables to ensure programs executed under root run as expected. ([sudo: java: command not found after exiting from root user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12309253/sudo-java-command-not-found-after-exiting-from-root-user))

So keep environment variables when using `sudo`:

```
sudo -E neo4j start
```